# MVC Controller Return Content before Update Div Content

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm using ajaxform with MVC.

How can I update div content like 
`return RedirectToAction("action","controller")`

but **before** calling like return `Content("Successfully update")` message with javascript or without javascript?

Like
Controller :

```
 if(Success)
    {
         return Content("Successfully updated");
    }
    else
    {
         return Content("Error");
    }
```

Razor:

```
<div id="result">
```

```
    <form action="/controller/action" data-ajax-update="#result" 
    data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="POST" data-ajax-mode="replace" method="post ">

<!-- Inputs was here -->
    </form>

    <div id="Content ">

<!-- DataList (partial content) was here -->    
    </div>
```

Comment: Please note that the model-view-controller tag is for questions about the pattern. There is a specific tag for the ASP.NET-MVC implementation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use AjaxOptions:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("action", "controller", new AjaxOptions 
                        { UpdateTargetId = "Content",
                          OnFailure = "OnFailure",
                          OnSuccess = "OnSuccess"}))
{
...
}
```

and then

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function OnSuccess(data) {
         $("#Content").html("Successfully updated");
    }
    function OnFailure(request, error) {
        alert("Error!");
    }

</script>
```

Comment: no. but if not successfully, content will be updated with error message.

Comment: @caras Could you please give me more details because now it is a little bit unclear what do you want

Comment: I think the answer of @MegaTron is already spot on.Use the OnSuccess and OnFailure functions to manipulate the data.

Comment: if successful, the content will be updated with partial content, if not with the result will be updated with alert message.

Comment: Do you mean that it will still send as success, but you will send in an error message instead that needs to be on alert?

Comment: but always will be return http200, so always will be call OnSuccess

Comment: it's not exactly like I wanted, but it's a nice solution, Thanks.

Comment: @caras Please accept the answer if it was helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The Controller should have checking then:

```
if(Success)
    {
         return Content("Successfully updated");
    }
    else
    {
         return Json(new { success = false, message = "Error!"});
    }
```

Then in the OnSuccess JS function:

```
function OnSuccess(data) {
        if (data.success === false){
             alert(data.message);
             $("#Content").html(data.message);
        }
        else
             $("#Content").html(data);

}
```